# -lpthread: Program runs on zsh terminal but won't run on linux bash

Tags: c, linux, macos, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I am on mac using VScode, when executing with: gcc Test2.c -o Test2 -lpthread. This works fine with. But when I do the same thing on linux bash, it returns that I have a segmentation fault.

I'm not sure where my memory problems are since there are no error messages.

This is my code (creating sorting algorithm using threads):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int arraysize;
int midarraysize;
int num1[10000];

typedef struct {
    int starting_index;
    int ending_index;
} pointer;

void *sorter(void *params); // MERGE SORT used
void *merger(void *params);

void merge(int arr[], int low1, int mid, int high1) {
    
    int i, j, k;
    int firststart = mid - low1 + 1;
    int secondstart = high1 - mid;
    int first[firststart], second[secondstart]; 
    for (i = 0; i < firststart; i++) {
        first[i] = arr[low1 + i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < secondstart; j++) {
        second[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = low1;

    while (i < firststart && j < secondstart) {
        if (first[i] <= second[j]) {
            arr[k] = first[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            arr[k] = second[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < firststart) {
        arr[k] = first[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < secondstart) {
        arr[k] = second[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}

void sort(int arg[], int low, int high) {
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high)/ 2;
        sort(arg, low, mid);
        sort(arg, mid+1, high);    
        merge(arg, low, mid, high);
    } else{
        return;
    }
}

int main(){ 

    FILE *IntList= fopen("IntegerList.txt", "r");
    
    char cIntlist[2000]; 
    char fullnum[100][100];
    int num[2000];

    int i, j, count, totalnum;

    fgets(cIntlist, 2000, IntList); //at some point, it stops reading the file

    for(i =0; i <= (strlen(cIntlist)); i++){
        if(cIntlist[i] == ','){// || NULL || '\0'){
            fullnum[count][j] = '\0' || NULL;
            count++;
            j = 0;
            totalnum ++;
            //printf("total number: %d\n", totalnum);
        } else {
            fullnum[count][j] = cIntlist[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    //printf("total number: %d\n", totalnum);

    printf("\n-----UNSORTED NUMBERS-----\n");

    for(i = 0;i < 2000;i++){
        //printf(" full sum%s\n", fullnum[i]);
        num[i] = atoi(fullnum[i]);
        if(num[i] == 0){
            //printf("indication\n\n");
            //printf("check size array: %lu\n\n", strlen(num));
            break;
        }
        printf("%d,",num[i]);
    }

    arraysize = totalnum +1;
    midarraysize = arraysize/2;
    
    //printf("\nnew array list:\n");
    //memcpy(num1[1000],num[2000], sizeof(num1));
    for(i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
        num1[i] = num[i];
    }
    for(i = 0;i < 2000;i++){
        num1[i] = atoi(fullnum[i]);
        //printf("%d,",num[i]);
        if(num1[i] == 0){
            //printf("indication\n\n");
            //printf("check size array: %lu\n\n", strlen(num));
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n\nMidpoint: %d", midarraysize);
    printf(", Array Size: %d\n", arraysize);
    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    
    // char *tparam1 = "sort1";
    // char *tparam2 = "sort2";
    // char *tparam3 = "merge";

    pointer *tparam1 = (pointer *)malloc(sizeof(pointer));
    pointer *tparam2 = (pointer *)malloc(sizeof(pointer));
    
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, sorter, tparam1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, sorter, tparam2);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    
    pthread_t thread3;
    pointer *tparam3 = (pointer *)malloc(sizeof(pointer));
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, merger, tparam3);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    
    FILE *outputfile = fopen("SortedIntegerList.txt", "w");

    fprintf(outputfile, "\n -----SORTED INTEGER LIST-----\n");
    printf("\n-----SORTED LIST-----\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i <= arraysize; i++){
        if(num1[i] == 0){
            break;
        }
        printf("%d,",num1[i]);
        fprintf(outputfile, "%d,", num1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    free(tparam3);
    free(tparam2);
    free(tparam1);
    fclose(outputfile);
    fclose(IntList);
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}


void *sorter(void *params){

    sort(num1, 0, midarraysize);
    sort(num1, midarraysize + 1, arraysize - 1);

    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *merger(void *params){

    merge(num1, 0, (arraysize/2), arraysize-1);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I'm not sure where the memory problems are, I would guess that the threads are not used correctly?

Comment: When you used a debugger, what did it tell you was causing the segfault?

Comment: Try compiling with `-fsanitize=address`, that may give you some hints.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, it didn't say there were any problems, it just says: Segmentation Fault

Comment: It is an obvious signs of undefined behaviour

Comment: `When you used a debugger, what did it tell you was causing the segfault?` `it just says: Segmentation Fault` So then, when the program is inside debugger and is stopped after a segmentation fault, use the debugger to get a backtrace, and see in which exact line the segfault occurs. And work from there to eliminating the bug. Remember to compile with debugging info enabled (`-g`).

Comment: @alagner, unfortunately, segmentation faults again

Comment: `unfortunately, segmentation faults again` And `-fsanitize=address -g` should give you the exact location of invalid write or read location, including stack trace and possibly even variable names. What is the sanitizer output? Are you sure you recompiled the program with sanitizer enabled and then rerun the program? || `fullnum[count][j] = '\0' || NULL;` is odd, it will assign the value `1` to it. What is `||NULL` doing there?  `FILE *outputfile =...`-  you do not check for errors, any `fopen` fail can cause seg fault. Add error checking.

Comment: Please also compile with warnings `-Wall -Wextra` and try fix them all warnings. Why are you running two `sorter` functions in parallel? Wouldn't they work on same set of data and overwrite their own results? Is there any synchronization between them? And why are `void *params` unused in thread functions?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your notes! I will try to implement all of those now, and yes, I understand my code is super messy, just started coding a month or so back!

Comment: You can also try using `valgrind` to run your program, it will detect many pointer problems and out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: Note the shells (zsh and bash) have nothing to do with this.  The relevant difference is MacOS versus Linux.  But even there, it's probably just that your buggy code happens to break in different ways between the two OSes, which is very common.

Comment: `pthread_exit(0);` main thread

Answer (score -1):

`pthread_exit(0);` main thread instead of do `join()`.  won't turn out good .